# In Word, why does "Align Justified" space out some text?

Tags: microsoft-word

Pls see GIF beneath. I added the green text myself. All other text, black and red, was pasted from an online court judgment.

1. When I click "Align Justified", why does Word space out the red text, but keep the green text aligned Left?
2. How can I command Word to align the red (and green) text Left, while aligning Justified everything else?

[image]

Comment: Please enable display of invisible characters (the `¶` button) and post a screenshot (you can [edit] the question)

Answer (score 2):

Word differentiates between two different kinds of linebreaks (I do not know the official names):

1. <kbd>Enter</kbd> ends a paragraph.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> ends a line.

In justified texts, the last line of a paragraph is aligned left instead.

So if there happens to be a 2. newline after the red text, it doesn't count as last line of a paragraph and will be blown up like you showed.

So you should be fine if you go to the end of the red line, mark the linebreak by <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right arrow key, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to replace the marked newline with a 1.-kind one.